# DLIB C++ how to make an std::vector of dlib::matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, std, dlib

I need a `std::vector` of  `dlib::matrix`, but I don't know at compile time the matrix size; documentation tells me:

```
// (Note that if you don't know the dimensionality of your vectors at compile time
// you can change the 2 to a 0 and then set the size at runtime)
typedef matrix<double,2,1> sample_type;
```

ok, but I need a `std::vector` of this objects, so what template argument I have to set on my `std::vector`?
example (`get_dimensionality()` gives me the right dimensionanlity):

```
matrix<double,0,1>  m;
m.set_size(get_dimensionality(),1);
std::vector<matrix<double,????????,1> v;
v.push_back(m);
```

what number at `????????` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the answer by your question. Use the vector as

```
std::vector<matrix<double, 0, 1> v;
```

so you can set each element size as it runs, the same you do with the matrices themselves.

Comment: but if I resize late...it's still compatible? example: v.at(0).set_size(get_dimensionality(),1); is no more <double, 0,1>, so I changed the object type in my std::vector...